# PHP-FPM not working on sockets but TCP only

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, socket

I have PHP5-FPM installed on Debian with nginx. When I try to open a PHP page then I get `Error 502 Bag Gateway`. I found out that it is because I am using sockets which looks like is not properly configured. I have tried to fix it by applying different settings but unable to solve this issue. If I change sockets to `127.0.0.1:9000` then it works fine.

Can you please check following configuration and tell me what am I doing wrong?

**pool.d/sf.conf**

> user = sf
>   group = sf
>   listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock
>   listen.owner = sf
>   listen.group = sf
>   pm = dynamic
>   pm.max_children = 5
>   pm.start_servers = 2
>   pm.min_spare_servers = 1
>   pm.max_spare_servers = 3
>   chdir =/

In above file I am using `/var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock` because `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` is already being used by `pool.d/www.conf`

**php5-fpm-sf.sock permission**

> srw-rw-rw- 1 sf sf 0 Aug 10 12:21 /var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock

**sites-available/sf**

> fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

> 2017/08/10 12:37:37 [crit] 11666#0: *3 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 162.125.12.13, server: www.sf.com,
>   request: "GET /phptest.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock:", host: "sf.com"

Comment: Have you verified 'sf' user permission on domain's root directory?

Comment: Root directory has this permission `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 10 10:48 html`. Does it look ok?

Comment: I tested by giving my `testfile.php` full permissions `777` but it shows same error so I guess it is not related to permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change listen.owner and listen.group to www-data in your pool conf file

```
user = sf
group = sf
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-sf.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

And don't forget to restart fpm and nginx service

Comment: Thanks it fixed the issue. There is small mistake in your answer i.e. it should be `www-data` in last line.